# C++ Destruction Dependencies

Tags: c++, winapi, destructor

I have a C++ class that needs to track resource usage, and when the last instance referencing the specific resource is destructed, the resource must be released. Due to the nature of how this resource can be acquired by multiple different objects (and not just through a copy / move constructor), I've had to implement my own reference tracking.

This reference tracking works great with very little performance hit, but when I started adding threading, I had to add a critical section to guard accesses to the reference counting structure. The critical section is a static member of the class that uses it. This works fine until the process begins exiting, and it's time for everything's destructor to be called.

What's happening is that the critical section's destructor (which calls `DeleteCriticalSection`) is being called before the last destructor of my objects. The result is that I'm stuck with either possible race conditions on my reference counter or a crash from trying to enter an invalid critical section.

These objects have a clear dependency on this critical section, and I don't see a great way to prevent it from being destroyed until the last object is gone. My thinking is to change the critical section from a static member to a `std::shared_ptr<CriticalSection>` belonging to each instance of the class, but that seems like it'd have an unnecessary performance hit.

Is there some other way to outline this dependency? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do without a need for this dependency in the first place?

EDIT: To be clear, I tried using `std::shared_ptr` to handle reference tracking. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Here's a trivialized example of how it causes issues.

```
Object Get(){
    Object o1{ GetResourceIdentifier(3) };
    Object o2{ o1 }; // Copy constructor
    Object o3{ GetResourceIdentifier(3) };
    return o3;
}
void main(){
    auto test{ Get() };
    test.DoStuff();
}
```

Necessarily, when an object is instantiated, it will just open the same resource if it's already open. So o1, o2, and o3 will all refer to the same underlying resource in this example. But with `std::shared_ptr`, when `Get` returns, the shared pointer that `o1` and `o2` have will think that there are no references left and release the resource. Unfortunately, since `o3` refers to the same resource, its resource also gets freed here, meaning the call to `DoStuff` will go awry.

If you'd like to see the actual code (file is rather large), the source is [here](https://github.com/ION28/BLUESPAWN/blob/client-scan/BLUESPAWN-client/src/util/configurations/RegistryKey.cpp) and the header is [here](https://github.com/ION28/BLUESPAWN/blob/client-scan/BLUESPAWN-client/headers/util/configurations/Registry.h)

Comment: Instead of destructing it, can you just leak it.

Comment: "I've had to implement my own reference tracking." Yeah. Probably the source of the issue. Use shared_ptr all around, next time.

Comment: Wasn't that possible to use atomics instead of critical sections?

Comment: "like it'd have an unnecessary performance hit." also, unless its shows pretty high in the profiler results, it's premature optimization.

Comment: Without seeing your code I'm having a hard time imagining how your reference counting works that part of the structure implementing the reference count can be destroyed before all references are released. The whole point of ref counting is that things aren't destroyed while they're in use. As Jeffrey said, use shared_ptr.

Comment: Sounds like an "order of destruction fiasco". If so, you can use the "[nifty counter idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter)" to dance around it. (Cf. the [incomplete FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#nifty-counter-idiom) about this on the quasi-authoritative ISO C++ site.)

Comment: simply use *long* type variable as class member wich hold reference count and interlocked increment/decrement it in addref/release.

Comment: @JonathanPotter You're correct; if the reference counting structure is destroyed before all references are released, bad things happen. As far as I can tell, my implementation doesn't have that issue though.

Comment: Having a static structure shouldn't be necessary at all; using atomic variables for your reference counts will be more efficient and also avoids any static-deallocation-ordering issues.  (and using `shared_ptr` will save you from re-inventing that particular wheel if you'd prefer not to)

Comment: You defined the critical section after the unordered map, which means that the map is constructed first and destructs last. Swap the order so the critical section destructs after the map that's using it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm using a map for my reference counter, so would I just change that to a `std::atomic<std::unordered_map<...>>`?

Comment: is the resource identifier an int and is that int known at compile time? I.e. you always do `GetResourceIdentifier(3)` or do you also do `GetResourceIdentifier(read_int())`

Comment: @bolov No, I just trivialized what's actually going on for the purpose of making an understandable example. `GetResourceIdentifier(read_int())` is more realistic.

Comment: @metal that's "Static INITIALIZATION order fiasco" and that doesn't apply here. Also, the "nifty counter" idiom isn't widespread and works only for singletons. Lastly, function local static instances are by far the superior fix for this ever since c++11

Comment: @JamesMcDowell change it to `std::atomic<int>`, that's all you really need unless you are doing something beyond the normal reference-counting approach (and if you are, you might want to rethink that, as adding a `std::map` to every reference-counted object seems awfully heavyweight)

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` would work fine in your example. `o1` and `o2`'s destruction won't release the resource since it's also shared by `o3`, which is transferred to `main`.

Comment: @sehe The destruction order can also be a fiasco for similar reasons, and it can indeed apply here. Admittedly, we have very little context, but it sounds like it is a globalish object that is in play, which could be adapted to a nifty counter if the shoe fits -- which it may not! The nifty counter is *not* something that should be deployed willy nilly, but it has its uses.

Comment: @Quentin The resource in question here is a `HKEY` (`typedef`ed to `HANDLE`). If I make two shared pointers with `std::make_shared<HKEY>((HKEY) 4);` and `std::make_shared<HKEY>((HKEY) 4)`, even though the underlying data has the same value, it does not occupy the same space in memory. Therefore `std::shared_ptr` will fail. Trust me, I've tried it. If anyone has a solution that doesn't use `std::unordered_map` or `std::map` for this, I'd love to hear it... I just don't think there is one.

Comment: Ah, yes, if `GetResourceIdentifier` returns invalid shared pointers in the first place there's going to be trouble. But you seem to have some logic in there which merges equivalent requests to return a previous known `HKEY`. That logic just has to store `weak_ptr`s instead of raw `HKEY`s and clean them up once in a while. Unless the very API you're using returns duplicate `HKEY`s that it doesn't reference-count itself, but that would be pretty dumb on their part: your only choice would be to cache them yourself instead.

Comment: @Quentin The API I'm using is `RegOpenKeyExW`, which returns a raw `HKEY`. If the path I'm putting into `RegOpenKeyExW` is already open in another `HKEY` (this does happen), it'll instead return that HKEY. When I call `CloseHandle` on either of the `HKEY`s returned, I can no longer use it anywhere unless I open it again. I suppose I could make a wrapper for `RegOpenKeyExW` that wraps it in a `shared_ptr` if it's not found, or grabs an existing `shared_ptr` if it already has been opened...

Comment: @JamesMcDowell DO NOT call `CloseHandle()` on an `HKEY`, you MUST call `RegCloseKey()` instead. *EVERY* successful call to `RegOpenKeyEx()` or `RegCreateKeyEx()` REQUIRES a corresponding `RegCloseKey()` call. And you can't use `std::make_shared()` to store an `HKEY` in a `std::shared_ptr`, the default deleter that gets used will try to `delete` the `HKEY`, which is wrong. Open/Create the `HKEY` and pass it to `std::shared_ptr`'s constructor with a custom deleter that calls `RegCloseKey()`. Then the standard reference counting of `std::shared_ptr` will suffice.

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel interfacing with the Winapi, I have had a pretty smooth ride with Microsoft's [WIL](https://github.com/Microsoft/wil/wiki/RAII-resource-wrappers). My experience is with `wil::unique_hkey` but `wil::shared_hkey` should work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your use case can use `shared_ptr`, but the trick is to store `weak_ptr`s, otherwise your resource will not be freed until the end of the program:

```
struct Resource
{
    int id;
    Resource(int id):id{id}{};
    ~Resource() { std::cout << "~" << id << std::endl; }

    auto foo() { std::cout << "foo" << id << std::endl; }
};

std::shared_ptr<Resource> get_resource(int resource_id)
{
    static std::mutex mutex{};
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<Resource>> resource_map{};

    std::scoped_lock lock{mutex};

    auto& weak = resource_map[resource_id];

    if (!weak.lock())
    {
        auto shared = std::make_shared<Resource>(resource_id);
        weak = shared;

        return shared;
    }
    return weak.lock();
}
```

This works as follows: When request a resource `i`

- if there isn't any resource `i` with active owners: creates a new resource, returns a new shared_ptr and stores a weak_ptr to it
- if there is a resource `i` with active owners returns a new share_ptr to it

A resource `i`:

- will be created on the first `get_resource(i)` call
- will be deleted once there are no more owners to it (`get_resource` doesn't hold owners)
- once deleted a new resource will be recreated on the next `get_resource(i)` call
- there will never be more than 1 resources `i` at the same time

This seems to work, but be advised I have done only summary testing:

```
auto test()
{
    auto r0 = get_resource(1);

    auto r1 = get_resource(24);
    auto r2 = r1;
    auto r3 = get_resource(24);

    return r3;
}

int main()
{
    auto r = test();

    r->foo();
}
```

Outputs

```
~1
foo24
~24
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I don't control the `get_resource` function.

Comment: I don't think this solution will work very well. The first time `get_resource()` is called for a resource, it is allocated and the caller gets a `shared_ptr` to it, and the `unordered_map` gets a `weak_ptr` to it. When the caller is done using the `shared_ptr`, it gets destroyed, and if there are no other users of that resource at that moment then it gets destroyed as well, and the `weak_ptr` is nulled. On the next call to `get_resource()` for the same resource, it is re-allocated again, and then destroyed again, over and over. Kind of defeats the purpose of using a resource cache at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that is the behavior I understood the OP wants. I didn't see it as a resource cache, but as a mechanism to express the uniqueness of `Resource{i}`. If the OP want a resource cache, then yes, my answer is not appropriate at all.